# Starting multiple services inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I have the following:

```
# Start app and proxy
CMD service nginx start
CMD ["nodejs", "/src/index.js"]
```

Doing it this way, the Node server is running, but not nginx. Likewise, if I do something like:

```
# Start app and proxy
CMD service nginx start && nodejs /src/index.js
```

then nginx is running, but not Node.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Node and nginx can both be webservers, if you need both, spin up node in one container, nginx in a second container, put them on their own network, and they can communicate with each other via DNS, e.g. `http://node/api-call`

Comment: Are you running them on different ports...?

Comment: there is ways to make they run together, but it looks like the "_wrong_" way to user `docker`... the right way is to have one service per container, like others already said

Comment: I ended up getting it to run together with `RUN echo "nginx && nodejs /src/index.js" >> /scripts/start.sh;` and then `CMD /scripts/start.sh`. The reason I kept them together was because I only used nginx as a reverse proxy needed for the Node app. However, I do see the benefit of splitting them apart and linking them so that is the route I will take. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can split your problem with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

You will get one container with your `nginx` image and one container `app` with your node application.

Then just run a `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker legacy linking:

1. In nginx folder `docker build -t docker-nginx .`
2. In node folder `docker build -t docker-node .`
3. `docker run -d --name app docker-node`
4. `docker run -d --name nginx --link app:app docker-nginx`

Then you point to **app** in nginx config file. Like `app:3000`

You could also use docker-compose which would simplify image building and container running. Checkout [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).